# select2, x-editable and bootstrap-table compatibility

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3 and [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/). I would like to use 'tag' mode like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/N6bQE/394/) example.

When I use **select2** version 3.4.4 (like in x-editable example) my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/90/) works, but when I want to use the latest version 4.0.0 my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/91/) doesn't work.

I get error message:

*Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/inputData*

I tried to replace select2.js by select2.full.js, but in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/92/) case editable box is empty.

How can I make editable cells compatible with the latest version of select2?

**html**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" data-editable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count" data-editable="true">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count" data-editable="true">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description" data-editable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>ala</td><td>ele</td><td class="tag" data-toggle="manual" data-type="select2" data-value="na, an, sd">na,an,sd</td><td>asd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ala</td><td>ele</td><td class="tag">na,an,sd</td><td>asd</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ala</td><td>ele</td><td class="tag">na,an,sd</td><td>asd</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    editable: true
});

console.log($('.tag'));

var tagCells = $('.tag');
$(tagCells).each(function() {
    var tags = $( this ).children(":first").html().replace(/ /g,'').split(",");
    console.log(tags);
    $(this).editable({
        select2: {
            tags: tags,
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
        }
    });
});

$('.tag').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).editable('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3057 at the bottom of the conversation, it is mentioned that select2 4 doesn't operate anymore on `input` tags. If I understood, first you toggle the editing (and this will turn the cell into an `input`), and then you apply select2, which in version 4 doesn't support `input`s.

Comment: Also the select2 docs have a `select` in the example (https://select2.github.io/options.html): `<select data-tags="true" data-placeholder="Select an option"></select>`

Comment: Thank you, you can write it as an answer and i can award it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, select2 since version 4 can't be applied anymore to `<input/>` controls.
[Issue #3057](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3057) on select2's GitHub page mentions it:

> Now i added the new plugin in my code. But it is throwing this error:
> `Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/inputData`
> What causes it?
>
> **It was due to using it on input element**. Fixed. Thanks for informing.

Some debug of your fiddle show that indeed X-editable turns your table cell first into

```
<input type="hidden" value="na, an, sd">
```

and then applies select2 on it, which fails.
Also select2 [own documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html) implicitly suggest this; the correct way to initialize a tagged control is starting from a `<select/>`:

```
<select data-tags="true" data-placeholder="Select an option"></select>
```

And you can also check on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm6wnn8d/2/) that indeed using it on an input doesn't work and triggers the same error, you need a select instead.

To have X-editable and select2 4 to work together, you should find a way of injecting some code in between the creation of the hidden `input` element and the call of select2, to be able to turn it into a `select`, which is roughly the same as rewriting the X-editable--select2 bridge.
Unfortunately I am not proficient with X-editable code and I didn't manage to workaround the problem, but if it's necessary for you to use version 4 you may start from line 4900 of `select2.js`, where I put a breakpoint to check which real HTMLElement was being passed to select2:

[image: Debugging select2, found hidden input tag as source control for selet2]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to walk around the issue is to create the select2 manually after the select was generated by x-editable:

```
<a 
    href="#" 
    id="marthafaker"
    data-type="select"
    data-placement="right"
    class="editable editable-click"
    data-pk="@Model.PK" 
    data-value="@Model.ActionId"
    data-title="Select something"
    data-url="/Controller/Action" ></a>

<script>
    $('#marthafaker').editable({
        source: names
    }).on('shown', function(e, editable){
        editable.input.$input.select2({
            width: 400
        });
        editable.input.$input.select2('val', editable.input.$input.val());
    });
</script>
```